# Highlight current link selected anchored to content on the same page

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a list of links to the left and a fixed div with hidden overflow to the right of a web page.  The fixed div is wrapped around 3 additional divs with the same height as the fixed div.  Each div nested within the fixed div is linked to one of the links in the list to the left of the fixed div.

This works fine, it essentially simulates a hide/show effect with pure html/css.  Now what I have been trying to do is highlight the current link selected in the list of links like you would with a menu item in a navigation bar.  I did a similar example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDU45/1/).

I can't seem to be able to highlight the current link with pure html/css so I've been attempting to do it with PHP with no success.

Is there a way to do this without Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a:focus{
    border:solid 1px red;
}
```

will work partially, but only until focus is moved elsewhere.

If the page is reloaded with each click, then you could use PHP to read the #anchor from the URL and add a class to the appropriate link element.

Comment: The page isn't refreshed with each click since all of the content on the same page but hidden except for the content within the corresponding div linked to the current selected link.

Comment: Then you won't get much help from PHP; PHP is only executed when the page is fetched.